# Reloader item vs Reload+ upgrade

Tags: heavy-bullets

In [Heavy Bullets](http://store.steampowered.com/app/297120/), you play as the rescuer of your company's (virtual?) abandoned hunting ground.  You have a (unchangeable) clip size of 6 bullets, where your bullets are made of indestructible material, and you must pickup your own shots for ammo.

---

## The Reloader (item)

The "Reloader" is an item that can be found in keycard-locked rooms.  It consumes ammo from your reserves first, before going through your clip.

**Example:** If you have a full 6-shot clip, and 4 additional bullets, you can fire 4 shots before it starts using your 6-shot clip.

## Reload+ (upgrade)

The `Reload+` upgrade allows you reload 1 more bullet per reload, up to a maximum of a full clip (6).

---

**Which are the advantages of each?  Is there a strategy to using them?** (e.g. upgrade reload+ to 3, but then use the reloader instead) The reload+ upgrade can be quite costly if not purchased early (upgrading to a 6-shot-reload costs ~500 credits on the first level, if even possible).  The Reloader takes up an inventory slot which can be used for something more useful like ores, and potions.

Comment: While I created a tag for the game, the question is opinion based and therefore off-topic.

Comment: @ardaozkal Sorry, made the question less opinion-based now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still think that it is opinion based, if you manage to edit to a non-opinion-based state, I'll pull my close vote back. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase it to ask "what are the advantages of this versus that" ... this sort of question seems to pop up often but I don't know if your game has a definitive answer or not.

Comment: @Tharius Thanks for the suggestion, I modified my question to reflect so.